# Error when installing metasploit-framework on Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, metasploit

Basically I followed this link: http://hackerforhire.com.au/installing-metasploit-framework-on-os-x-yosemite/

However, after I finish all the steps and typing `./msfconsole`  the following error occurs:

```
/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/modules/payloads/stagers/android/reverse_tcp.rb:38:in `generate_jar': android/apk/classes.dex not found (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload/dalvik.rb:27:in `generate'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload.rb:199:in `size'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_set.rb:158:in `block (2 levels) in recalculate'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_set.rb:102:in `each_pair'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_set.rb:102:in `block in recalculate'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_set.rb:98:in `each_pair'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_set.rb:98:in `recalculate'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:284:in `block in load_modules'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:281:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/modules/loader/base.rb:281:in `load_modules'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:117:in `block in load_modules'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:115:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/loading.rb:115:in `load_modules'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:41:in `block in add_module_path'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/module_manager/module_paths.rb:40:in `add_module_path'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:53:in `block in add_engine_module_paths'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:52:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:52:in `add_engine_module_paths'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/base/simple/framework/module_paths.rb:16:in `init_module_paths'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/ui/console/driver.rb:220:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `new'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `driver'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in `start'
    from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:48:in `<main>'
```

It seems the path to android/apk/classes.dev is not correct, or does not exist.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have antivirus installed, then check that it's not blocking anything from metasploit. In my case quick fix was to disable "File System Shield" in Avast.